# Unable to download data from Firebase - TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to download user profiles from firebase and use them in a component. I'm having trouble with the async firebase function and useState. In the code below "profiles" repeatedly gets concatenated but it doesn't seem to update the "cards" prop in the Swiper component which still gets an empty array.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Swiper from 'react-native-deck-swiper'
import { Card } from '../components/Card'
import { View } from '../components/Themed';
import firebaseSDK from '../database/firebase'

export default function HomeScreen() {
  const [profiles,setProfiles] = React.useState([])
  firebaseSDK.db
    .ref('userProfile')
    .once('value')
    .then((snapshot)=>{
      //this line prints the profiles correctly
      console.log("snapshot Val profiles : " + JSON.stringify(Object.values(snapshot.val())))
      setProfiles(prevState => prevState.concat(Object.values(snapshot.val())))
    })
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Swiper
      cards={profiles}
      renderCard={Card}
    />
}
```

using this code I get

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'cards.length')
```

Even though the console log shows "profiles" is continuously growing bigger as it gets repeatedly concatenated. What's the process to access the data correctly?

EDIT:

some more details about the code

the data I'm downloading looks like this :

```
{
  "id1":{
    avatar: "https://placebear.com/200/300",
    displayName: 'Fakeman Fakeaccount',
    AboutMe: '16 miles away',
    uid:1234
  },
  "id2":{
    avatar: "https://placebear.com/200/300",
    displayName: 'Joanna, 19',
    AboutMe: '2 miles away',
    uid:1234
  },
  "id3":{
    avatar: "https://placebear.com/200/300",
    displayName: 'Charlie, 32',
    AboutMe: '24 miles away',
    uid:1234
  },
}
```

`cards` takes an array of objects, which is why I initialized useState with an "[]" and I ran `Object.values` on `snapshot.val()` to turn it into an array.

The Card component:

```
export const Card = ({ avatar, displayName, AboutMe, uid }) => (
  <Tile
    // imageSrc={avatar}
    imageSrc={{uri:avatar}}
    imageContainerStyle={styles.imageContainer}
    activeOpacity={0.9}
    title={displayName}
    titleStyle={styles.title}
    caption={AboutMe}
    captionStyle={styles.caption}
    containerStyle={styles.container}
    key={uid}
    featured
  />
)
```

`Swiper` takes an array of data (`cards` prop) and uses it to populate multiple `Card` components (`renderCard` prop)

EDIT 2:

Thanks to @DougStevenson the download problem is solved (update state inside a `useEffect` block)

```
  const [profiles,setProfiles] = React.useState([
    {
      avatar: "https://placebear.com/200/300",
      displayName: 'Placeholder',
      AboutMe: 'Im not real',
      uid:"000000000000000000"
    },
  ])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    firebaseSDK.db
    .ref('userProfile')
    .once('value', (snapshot)=>{
      //returns an array [{...},{...},{...},...]
      console.log(JSON.stringify(Object.values(snapshot.val())))
      setProfiles(Object.values(snapshot.val()))
    })
```

However now `setProfiles` truncates the data into a single element array. I think this is because of how I defined the initial state and because I'm using a TypeScript template it's finicky about definitions?

EDIT 3 :

Ok so it turns out it was the `Swiper` component which was messing up. `Swiper` is a stack of `View`s, it initialized with an array of length 1 which means it created 1 `View` in the stack. When I updated the `cards` prop it only updated the 1 `View` in the stack and didn't add more `View`s.

Comment: Since database queries are asynchronous and don't compete immediately, you will want to put your query in a useEffect hook.  When your component renders the first time, `profiles` will be undefined.

Comment: @DougStevenson OP actually provides an initial value of `[]` for the state object.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Then I wonder what `cards` could be.

Comment: @DougStevenson The `useEffect` fixed it! Thanks! However now I'm having a problem with `setProfiles` which updates the state, could you check the latest edit? I think this is mostly a TypeScript issue now and I'm not sure how to figure it out

Comment: Ok so it turns out it was the `Swiper` component which was messing up. `Swiper` is a stack of `View`s, it initialized with an array of length 1 which means it created 1 `View` in the stack. When I updated the `cards` prop it only updated the 1 View in the stack and didn't add more `View`s. I still haven't figured out what to do about this but it's out of the scope of the question. If you post an answer with useEffect I'd be happy to mark it solved @DougStevenson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since database queries are asynchronous and don't compete immediately, you will want to put your query in a useEffect hook so that the component knows when to render with new content.